# EclipseLink is not logging Finer or Finest level only fine

Tags: eclipselink, entitymanager

I have in persistance.xml

```
<persistence-unit name="callrecunit">
...
<properties>
  <property name="eclipselink.logging.level.sql" value="FINER"/>
  <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINER"/>
  <property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true"/>
</properties>
```

but the best logging level is FINE.

```
   <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" >

  <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="callrecunit"/>
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>

  <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter">
      <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
      <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.PostgreSQLPlatform"/>

    </bean>
  </property>
  <property name="jpaDialect">
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaDialect"/>
  </property>
  <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
    <bean class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver"/>
  </property>
</bean>
```

I know I have logging messages on FINER or FINES, but it is never logged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem is in EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter definition.
I have to commet out:

```
<!--<property name="showSql" value="true"/>-->
```

And it started logging on higher level.

I did some debugging and if showSQL is enabled, then this is considered as FINE level, which is then not overwriten by persistance settings. - only null values of logging level are overwriten, since FINE is valid, even more detailed levels are not used... Maybe bug?

Comment: This would be a good question for the Eclipselink Users mailing list which is monitored by devs.

Comment: The spring config is used to overwrite persistence unit settings.  If you set this value, it is taken as the current state and overwrites the Eclipselink logging.level values.  Any change would have to come from Spring to check what is already set so that it only sets it to FINE if the value was >FINE already.  (numerically 0 is all, 8 is OFF)